# recover files from HSF+ USB External HD, test on CentOS 7 to diagnostic

Tags: centos, osx, data-recovery, external-hdd, hfs+

Note:

The result for my question are very different to [How to repair a corrupted HFS+ partition from a damaged hard-disk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109673/how-to-repair-a-corrupted-hfs-partition-from-a-damaged-hard-disk)

For another result with ubuntu:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/955325/using-gpart-testdisk-to-recover-gpt-for-files-from-damaged-hfs-apple-hd

I have USB, External Hard Drive with **HSF+** File System.

The problem is that I can't to extract my files on MAC with **macOS Sierra 10.12.6**, even using commercial tools like:

- Tech Tool Pro 9
- DiskWarrior 5
- Disk Drill
- Data Rescue 4 (now I'm testing).

With macOS Sierra I ran the next commands:

- diskutil verifyVolume /dev/disk2s2

  `The volume ADATAHD could not be verified completely
  File system check exit code is 8
  Error: -69845: File system verify or repair failed
  Underlying error: 8: Exec format error`
- diskutil repairVolume /dev/disk2s2

  `File system check exit code is 8
  Updating boot support partitions for the volume as required
  Error: -69610: Error parsing fsck program XML format output
  Underlying error: 8: Exec format error`
- sudo fsck_hfs -fryd /dev/disk2s2

  `unknown volume type 
  primary MDB is at block 0 0x00 
  alternate MDB is at block 0 0x00 
  primary VHB is at block 0 0x00 
  alternate VHB is at block 0 0x00 
  sector size = 512 0x200 
  VolumeObject flags = 0x01 
  total sectors for volume = 1952853344 0x74662d60 
  total sectors for embedded volume = 0 0x00 
  CheckForClean - unknown volume type 
  CheckHFS returned 6, fsmodified = 0`
- sudo gpt -r show disk0

  `gpt show: unable to open device 'disk2': Resource busy`
- sudo diskutil repairDisk disk2

  `Problems were encountered during repair of the partition map
  Error: -69808: Some information was unavailable during an internal lookup`

I was reading this post: [How to repair a corrupted HFS+ partition from a damaged hard-disk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109673/how-to-repair-a-corrupted-hfs-partition-from-a-damaged-hard-disk) but the error codes are different!.

**I want to know your porpoise te begin my test using CentOS 7.**

My question to get solution on Apple. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/296151/recover-files-from-corrupted-external-usb-hd-macos-sierra

I put this question here because I want attempt using CentOS 7 side too!

Thank you.

**EDIT 1**

Map of disks!

```
[root@localhost liveuser]# lsblk
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                8:0    0   113G  0 disk 
├─sda1             8:1    0   200M  0 part 
├─sda2             8:2    0 112.2G  0 part 
└─sda3             8:3    0 619.9M  0 part 
sdb                8:16   1   7.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1             8:17   1   1.7G  0 part /run/initramfs/live
├─sdb2             8:18   1   4.9M  0 part 
└─sdb3             8:19   1  19.7M  0 part 
sdd                8:48   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdd1             8:49   0   200M  0 part 
└─sdd2             8:50   0 931.2G  0 part 
loop0              7:0    0    20K  1 loop 
loop1              7:1    0   4.4M  1 loop 
└─live-osimg-min 253:2    0     8G  1 dm   
loop2              7:2    0   1.6G  1 loop 
loop3              7:3    0     8G  1 loop 
├─live-rw        253:0    0     8G  0 dm   /
├─live-base      253:1    0     8G  1 dm   
└─live-osimg-min 253:2    0     8G  1 dm   
loop4              7:4    0   512M  0 loop 
└─live-rw        253:0    0     8G  0 dm   /
[root@localhost liveuser]#
```

*With fsck*

```
[root@localhost liveuser]# fsck /dev/sdd2
fsck from util-linux 2.23.2
e2fsck 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
fsck.ext2: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sdd2
Could this be a zero-length partition?
[root@localhost liveuser]#
```

*With fsck.hfsplus*

```
[root@localhost liveuser]#  fsck.hfsplus /dev/sdd2
** /dev/sdd2
   Executing fsck_hfs (version 540.1-Linux).
[root@localhost liveuser]#
```

*With fdisk -l*

```
[root@localhost liveuser]# fdisk -l
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/sda: 121.3 GB, 121332826112 bytes, 236978176 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: gpt


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1           40       409639    200M  EFI System      EFI System Partition
 2       409640    235708599  112.2G  Apple Core stor ElCapitanHD
 3    235708600    236978135  619.9M  Apple boot      

Disk /dev/sdb: 8017 MB, 8017412096 bytes, 15659008 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x79bec633

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           0     3465215     1732608    0  Empty
/dev/sdb2             172       10231        5030   ef  EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sdb3           10280       50599       20160    0  Empty

Disk /dev/sdb1: 1774 MB, 1774190592 bytes, 3465216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x79bec633

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1p1   *           0     3465215     1732608    0  Empty
/dev/sdb1p2             172       10231        5030   ef  EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sdb1p3           10280       50599       20160    0  Empty

Disk /dev/mapper/live-rw: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/live-base: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/live-osimg-min: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdd: Input/output error
[root@localhost liveuser]#
```

Comment: Run fsck from a Centos 7 recover image and see if you get further than the MAC OS version.

Comment: @RamanSailopal my results, sorry but I was working with a USB KDE Live Version.