# dd, ddrescue, dd_rescue performance according to OS (Ubuntu, macOS)

Tags: osx, performance, dd, external-hdd, ddrescue

I put this question:

[recover files from HSF+ USB External HD, test on CentOS 7 to diagnostic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388982/recover-files-from-hsf-usb-external-hd-test-on-centos-7-to-diagnostic)

And this

https://askubuntu.com/questions/955325/using-gpart-testdisk-to-recover-gpt-for-files-from-damaged-hfs-apple-hd

I'm trying to recover my data files from a External `3.0USB` 1TB Hard Disk (`HFS+` File System) can be identified with the Black color, then I have another with the same characteristic to copy my recovered files with the Gray color. On Ubuntu I can't write using `HFS+` then I formatted the HDD Destiny/Gray like `Ext4` File System.

I can see the tree and the files in Ubuntu, but in macOS not (using Finder)!!!

I can't see my files on **macOS Sierra** my Hard Disk have HFS+ File System (originally used by macOS).

[image: I can't see my files on **macOS Sierra**]

Strangely I can see using **Ubuntu** the files
[image: I can see using **Ubuntu** the Files of external <code>HFS+</code> HDD]

Now I'm using `ddrescue` on **Linux Ubuntu 17.04**.  but it is possible to use this command on **macOS Sierra** too!

But my machine (MacBook Air) only has two `3.0USB` ports.
Like I haven't Ubuntu installed, I need a Live Version, using a Stick (I have a `3.0USB` 16GB Stick).
But the disks `Source/Black` and `Destiny/Gray` are External, then I need a USB Hub.

Here my Scenario to recover my files.[image]

Then to use a Ubuntu Live through a external `3.0USB` Stick I need to use a USB hub, only I have a `2.0USB Hub` with Silver color, and the speed allowed on `2.0USB` is *sensible* lower than `3.0USB`.

This `ddrescue` can take **months** using `2.0USB` Hub to connect the Two HDD's in recover process.

**QUESTIONS:**

Can I to do this process on **macOS Sierra** side (with its SSD HDD - only I have 15GB free space), using the two `3.0USB` ports  to connect the Source/Black and Destiny/Gray (using `HFS+` File System) HDD's to improve the speed?.

Can be the results different?

In the `dd` command is recommended to unmount the hard disk's, is needed in **ddrescue** and **dd_rescue** too?

**NOTE:**

I-m trying to recover my data on **macOS** side in this questions:

[recover Files from corrupted External USB HD, macOS Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/296151/recover-files-from-corrupted-external-usb-hd-macos-sierra)

[using gpt : unable to open device ..': Resource busy](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297562/using-gpt-unable-to-open-device-resource-busy)

Comment: If your disks have different geometries you can't just copy the raw images with `dd` or `ddrescue`. Format the destination disk, mount both disks, and copy your files with `rsync` or `dump` / `restore`. Also when you're using an USB hub the entire traffic through the hub is limited to the speed of the port your hub is plugged to. Find a machine with two USB 3 ports, preferably on different controllers, and do the transfer there. Otherwise it will take forever and a day.

Comment: Then I can't use `HFS+` in one side and `Ext4` in another. Then the best option is to use `ddrescue` on macOS side because I will be using the machine's internal HDD (with Sierra) and I can use freely the two `3.0USB` ports. But why I can't see the files on macOS side like Ubuntu (without size)?

Comment: Read this carefully: _you can't use `ddrescue` if your disks have different geometries_. You can't see your files because what you're doing doesn't make sense.

Comment: @SatōKatsura The damaged disk has `HFS+` originally, but in macOS Sierra I can't see the files to be recovered, but in Ubuntu I can see the files (still ubuntu is `Ext4` based on). Then to use `dd`/`ddrescue` I will need to reformat the Destiny HDD like `HFS+` again to have Source and Destiny in the same File System. The problem is Ubuntu don't let me write on HFS+ HDD.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use `ddrescue` but `testdisk`. You can get `testdisk` for Mac OS X here: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Then all you need is to hook up your two disks, open the `Terminal` (`/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`), change directory into your "Destiny" volume. You can see the name of the volume in finder, locate it under `/Volumes`: perform the following in Terminal: `ls /Volumes` and locate the name of the volume. Next, change directory: `cd '/Volumes/<name_of_volume>'`, then you run `testdisk` (you will have to place it somewhere, assuming it is on your desktop in folder `testdisk`), `~/Desktop/testdisk/testdisk`, make sure you select the correct source and target drives and let it run over the night.

See http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step for exact steps in testdisk.

Comment: Here my result with TestDisk and PhotoRec https://askubuntu.com/questions/955325/using-gpart-testdisk-to-recover-gpt-for-files-from-damaged-hfs-apple-hd

Comment: It looks like your drive is in a dire state, I would say, almost unrecoverable without specialist tools. In the ubuntu thread, you claim to be able to get a directory tree, fine, can you copy paste a directory from that to another drive ? I doubt it.

Comment: Thank you, have you some name for specialist tools recommended for this situation?